# SVG title tooltip not shown when using dynamic input and mousemove in Angular

Tags: angular, svg

Given the following Angular application, the SVG `title`s will be shown as tooltips (upon hovering) for the first `HelloComponent`'s `rect`s, but not for the others. If you remove the `(mousemove)` attribute, all tooltips are shown. What is happening here? How to fix?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-df8cxp?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `
    <svg (mousemove)="onMouseMove($event)">
      <rect
        *ngFor="let item of items"
        [attr.x]="item.x"
        width="10"
        height="100%"
      >
        <title>{{ item.x }}</title>
      </rect>
    </svg>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      :host {
        display: flex;
      }

      svg {
        flex-grow: 1;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() items: { x: number }[];

  onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent) {}
}
```

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <hello [items]="items1"></hello>
    <hello [items]="items2"></hello>
    <hello [items]="getItems3()"></hello>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  items1 = [{ x: 100}, { x: 150 }];

  get items2() {
    return [{ x: 200}, { x: 250 }];
  }

  getItems3() {
    return [{ x: 300}, { x: 350 }];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve the problem is to avoid binding items to a property getter (like `items2`) or to a method (like `getItems3`) that systematically creates a new array.

Another solution is to track the `rect` elements by index in the `*ngFor` loop:

```html
<rect *ngFor="let item of items; trackBy: trackByIndex" ...>
  ...
</rect>
```

```js
trackByIndex(index, item) {
  return index;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vnmhpu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) for a demo.